# MobileIron SSO with custom auth provider

Tags: mobile, single-sign-on, mdm, siteminder, mobileiron

Is it possible to have SSO across multiple apps, installed through MobileIron, that connect to back-end services/sites protected by SiteMinder or any custom authorization provider ?

Looking at this [Stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988121/mobileiron-with-sharepoint-for-authentication/29169989#29169989) and [MobileIron video](https://www.mobileiron.com/en/resources/videos/ios-7-enterprise-single-sign-sso-explained), it seems like the MobileIron SSO can be against KDC only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you're quiet right: SSO capabilities to Intranet applications located behind MobileIron Sentry are provided via KCD. The possibility to do this via user certificates managed through MobileIron seems not to work (look at this thread [iOS Client Certificates and Mobile Device Management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924881/ios-client-certificates-and-mobile-device-management)).Third party / custom authentication providers like SAML are not supported at the moment by MobileIron.

Comment: We were able to do certificate-based authentication by configuring MI to provide the app with a base 64 encoded cert (.p12 file) and password, which we pass to the server. After decoding the cert, the user's LDAP email is in the cert for associating with that user.